# extract specific data from a csv file in Python with csv package

Tags: python, csv

I have a 14000 lines with two fields each csv file and am trying to remove some rows that occur randomly. I intend to keep everything besides the rows containing any of the following: "Station Name", "Location Code", "Parameter".

I am trying to open the file containing the data together with a new empty csv file that will be used to write the new data into.
I am trying to loop through each line of the csv file and write into the new file only the lines which do not have the first field equal to any of the mentioned values.

I am trying the following but I end up with an exact copy of the initial data.

```
import csv
with open('combined_csv.csv', newline='') as inp, open('edited.csv', 'w', newline='') as out:
    writer = csv.writer(out)

    for row in csv.reader(inp):
        if row[0] != "Station Name" and "Location Code" and "Parameter":
            writer.writerow(row)
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your if statement won't work as you expected. If you want to check string to be not equal with several strings I recommend you to do like this:

```
if row[0] not in ("Station Name", "Location Code", "Parameter"):
    writer.writerow(row)
```

**Upd.**

> Your version works well but why is mine not working?

```
if row[0] != "Station Name" and "Location Code" and "Parameter":
```

You're trying to check `row[0]` to be not equal with `"Station Name" and "Location Code" and "Parameter"`.

Let's print it:

```
>>>"Station Name" and "Location Code" and "Parameter"
'Parameter'
```

Why? Let's do some experiments:

```
>>>"Station Name" and "Location Code" and "Test"
'Test'

>>>False and "Station Name" and "Location Code" and "Test"
False

>>>"" and "Station Name" and "Location Code" and "Test"
''

>>>"Station Name" and "Location Code" and "" and "Test"
''
```

Still have questions? Okay:

```
>>bool("Non-empty string")
True

>>>bool("")
False
```

So, your code is equivalent of

```
if row[0] != "Parameter":
```

**How to write it properly.**

```
if row[0] != "Station Name" and row[0] != "Location Code" and row[0] != "Parameter":
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Your version works well but why is mine not working?

Comment: @pba see the proposed duplicate; it's a common problem

Comment: @pba, I've updated my answer.

Comment: Clear now. Thanks!

Comment: @pba, If you want to use my variant, than better to use variant proposed in duplicate question with set. I mean `if row[0] not in {"Station Name", "Location Code", "Parameter"}:`